# ATMega128 A/D Floating

Tags: avr, adc, atmega

I'm working with an ATMega128 micro working with a joystick (pot in the schematic below) that's a .25-4.75V output with a 2ohm output impedance (Joystick Part Number is: ch products ts-2-r-1-u-05-a).  When the line between the pot and the 33kohm resistor gets removed while the board is on however, the voltage will float ~.5V for a period of time (20-30 minutes maybe) before pulling down completely.  I was thinking that the 499kohm resistor should pull it down effectively, but something doesn't seem quite right on this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvGcpu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Anyone have ideas as to why it wouldn't pull down completely and immediately? I've watched it on a scope and it hovers for quite a while around that .5V mark. Also to note, I'm currently piggybacking the 499kohm resistor onto the .01uF cap for testing.

Comment: Your R2/C1 circuit has a time constant of about 5ms. So if your input does not return to ground within about 30ms, something else is driving the node too. Do you maybe have the internal pull-ups of the mcu enabled?

Comment: @Curd it's the part number of the joystick for reference. Thought it might be useful to include.

Comment: @svens I'll look into that, but I believe the ATMega128 disables pullups while in A/D mode. The 499k wasn't originally there so I added it (piggybacked onto the cap) last night and it wouldn't pull down for anything. Let it stay on overnight, and this morning it worked every time until I unplugged it again. Not sure what's going on there, but I'll look into the pullups.

Comment: @biggidvs: then why don't you say that this is a part number? It's not obvious at all. BTW: Since you wonder about the circuit's behaviour when the joystick is disconnected, how can it matter at all?

Comment: @Curd just trying to include every piece of information. It's when unplugging the joystick from that line that the voltage doesn't pull down. Because it's part of my sequence of steps to replicate the issue, I included it.  I'll edit to show it' a part number.

Comment: @biggidvs: How did you measure the voltage at node "A/D"? 499k is quite a high resistance. Your finger touching two lines may have a resistance that is a fraction (1/20 or even less) of that.

Comment: Another possibility is that R2 isn't properly attached.

Comment: Yea I've thought that and resoldered it multiple (probably 20 or 30) times. It's hard to measure the resistance from that line to ground with that cap being there (it likes to float a bit). Part of me wants to remove the cap and go from there. It's just a filter of sorts...might introduce a bit more noise but would allow me to see the issue maybe.

Comment: Is your ground connection actually good (low impedance) of that cap and resistor? I've had a via bug me for some hours because it didn't make right contact...

Comment: @Arsenal yes I have 0.2ohms from the ground of the cap/resistor to the ground coming in on the board.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that the ATmega itself has no influence on the node voltage.

In fact, if you look at the data sheet, the input leakage current is specified as up to a microamp in either direction.

A microamp across 499K is half a volt.

This might or might not be the explanation for the actual issue you see, but it is an example of an *invalid design assumption* - regardless if this is what is happening or not, it's a situation fully allowed by the data sheet, and therefor a design error to assume that it will not happen.

Comment: Right I see that and it appears that that might be where it's coming from. I can get some smaller resistor values and try those to see if it pulls it down harder and to get away from the node influence. However, with the 33k ohm series resistance, I need to stay above that for the pulldown correct?

Comment: Perhaps you should back up and think about why you care?  Are you trying to detect a missing joystick?  If your specification of the joystick were correct, you could put stronger bias resistors upstream of the series resistor without much effect, but your spec for the joystick just isn't believable unless it has a buffer amplifier.

Comment: Yes, trying to detect if it comes unplugged/etc. For example, without a pulldown, if the joystick comes unplugged when it's reading ~3V, then the line will float at 3V since there is no path to ground. That's why I'm adding a pulldown (to pull it out of the operating range to detect an error mode). The 33k resistor is already there, so I'm trying to work around it the best I can. Didn't know if a smaller pulldown would effect that or not.

Comment: If you really want to detect the joystick you may need to do something like periodically inject pulses of current and see that their effect is limited, or chop the supply to the joystick on and off and see that the reading responds.  But you'll need careful synchronization and management of RC time constants to make sure that the readings your use for data aren't affected by the presence detect operations.

Comment: So you think a smaller pulldown will change the output from the joystick?

Comment: Changing to a 100k resistor does fix the issue and it pulls down instantly...now time to fix the output issue.

Comment: Fixed by changing 33k to 1k and 100k pulldown eliminating most of the effect of the voltage divider. Will update final schematic with answer. The ATMega was effecting the node causing issues so it was just a matter of balancing leakage current with the voltage divider!